# Forwarding WebRTC stream to a rtmp server

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, webrtc, kurento

How can I take the input stream and forward it to my rtmp server, is there a simple way for me to do that or is using kurento/other WebRTC server mandatory?

Comment: even jitsi is a good option

Comment: Also check https://antmedia.io and https://flussonic.com/

Answer (score 1):

there is no direct way to do this. you need a media server.